# If given $\overline {x^2}=0$, is $\bar x=0$?

Tags: integration, calculus

If $$\bar x=\frac{\int_V x\, \mathrm dv}{\int_V\, \mathrm dv} $$ and if given $\overline {x^2}=0$, is it necessary that $\bar x=0$?

Comment: Are $x$ real numbers?

Comment: Ya real and positive @noah

Comment: This belongs on Mathematics SE

Comment: As x=0 so is its average.

Answer (score 5):

$\int_V x^2(v)dv = 0 \, \Leftrightarrow \, x(v)=0 \, \forall \, v\in V$ since $x^2(v)\geq0 \, \forall \, v$.

Therefore $\int_V x(v)dv = 0$ as well.

Of course, I assumed $x$ real here.

Comment: $\int_V x^2(v)dv = 0 \iff x \equiv 0 $ almost everywhere in $V$ $ \implies \int_V x(v)dv = 0$.

Comment: why did you add the use of "almost"?

Comment: Because if, for example, we set $x(0) = 1$, then the integral still vanishes, but $x(v)$ is not identically zero. It's a common expression in integration theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. I have a physics background.